# How to activate pipe in Angular if model changed?

Tags: angular

I have filter pipe that I use to filter array of objects. Filter pipe has dependency injection by service.
Service has model data `filterService.data`.

How to activate pipe in template only when model in service is changed?

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private filterService: FilterService) {}

    transform(array: any, start?: any, end?: any): any {}
}
```

**Using:**

```
 *ngFor="let item of response | filter"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Angular pipe is pure by default. It only triggers an update when any of the **input parameters** change. It's the only way that you can "activate" the pipe (update its result). Any dependency service that the pipe uses is internal and irrelevant to the pipe consumer which is responsible for re-rendering its view after detecting changes to the data fed to the pipe.

So in your example, only when Angular detects a change in either `array`, `start` or `end`, then it activates the pipe. Once again, changing those parameters is the only way to control the re-application of the pipe. So the proper way to make the pipe update after a change in model is to propagate the change via any of the input parameters fed into the pipe. Then inside the pipe you can apply the transformation service to the data to produce the desired result. Do not feed the service with any data outside of this flow, or it will never be caught up by change detection. Making the pipe depend on external data like that is prone to side effects, violating the rule that a pure pipe must be a pure function.

Say if you want to add more sorting criteria to the filter, you should modify your pipe like this:

```
 transform(array: any[], start?: any, end?: any, orderBy?: string, descending?: boolean): any[] {}
```

To ensure any change on those criteria triggers update on the pipe by way of the passed parameters.

Now look at `array`: rather than an option to pass to the filter service (which is usually a scalar value), the first parameter to the pipe always specifies the target that the pipe acts on, usually an array (non-scalar). When this array is changed, the pipe should be activated too, but there's a catch. Since arrays are passed by reference, even if you modify the source array, if the change is in place, the array is still considered to be the same, so no change is detected as far as the pipe is concerned. So when you update the source array, like fetching a new page of items, if you want to trigger update, it is important to change the array itself, not just mutate its content:

```
  array = [...array, newItem];  // NOT array.push(newItem);
```

Stick to that rule then your pipe will behave well.

Pipes are a convenient way to customize your view, but try not to overuse them. Move the transformation task into the component rendering logic (or better consuming a shared service), as advised by the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes):

> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly
>   recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component
>   itself.

That way you have more control over how and when you present data, and might gain efficiency as you could filter out a subset of data for optimal rendering, instead of wiring all through to expensive pipes and back as we're all used to.

Comment: when any of the input parametersm do you mean `@input()` or parameters of `transform()`?

Comment: @MeganClerc  parameters of `transform()` which is equivalent to `@Input()` for pipes

Answer (score 1):

Fast solution - impure pipe, will be updated with every change, even if it is unnecessarily:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
```

But this solution is not acceptable in terms of performance.

Pure pipes update after value or args was changed, bbut if the reference to the array does't changed, pipe will not be updated. You can try update reference on array after change array: `response = [...response]`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#detecting-impure-changes-within-composite-objects

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking in the template, you could keep state of the model in the service and apply the transformation only if it satisfies your condition.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private filterService: FilterService) {}

  transform(array: any, start?: any, end?: any): any {
    if (filterService.applyTransform) {
      // apply transformation
    } else {
      return array;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but pipe is not detect changes, to activate pipe should be action outside, is not?